# How do I run Selenium IDE recorded tests consistently against several environments?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-automation-framework, selenium-ide

I'm looking to record automated tests against a web application using Selenium IDE.

I want to run these tests automatically against various environments.

Is this possible? From what I have read, I can export them and run them that way but I'm unsure about how to do this and what I would need.

I am essentially starting from scratch and have no experience with code.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to use the 'Base URL' in IDE.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#using-base-url-to-run-test-cases-in-different-domains

> The Base URL field at the top of the Selenium-IDE window is very
>   useful for allowing test cases to be run across different domains.
>   Suppose that a site named http://news.portal.com had an in-house beta
>   site named http://beta.news.portal.com. Any test cases for these sites
>   that begin with an open statement should specify a relative URL as the
>   argument to open rather than an absolute URL (one starting with a
>   protocol such as http: or https:). Selenium-IDE will then create an
>   absolute URL by appending the open command’s argument onto the end of
>   the value of Base URL.

Another approach is to save your test suite in different names after changing the Base URL upfront.

> Like most programs, there are Save and Open commands under the File
>   menu. However, Selenium distinguishes between test cases and test
>   suites. To save your Selenium-IDE tests for later use you can either
>   save the individual test cases, or save the test suite. If the test
>   cases of your test suite have not been saved, you’ll be prompted to
>   save them before saving the test suite. When you open an existing test
>   case or suite, Selenium-IDE displays its Selenium commands in the Test
>   Case Pane.